# Java ObjectOutput will not write object, IO write exception

Tags: java, serialization

I am having trouble getting my serialize objects to be written to a file. My save routine always fails at ObjectOutput.writeObject(..)

I have a Inventory class that holds a linked list of items. MainView is the main JFrame of the program it also holds the Inventory object.

I have had this working before, but I decided to rewrite a vast majority of my program. It seems I have done something to screw it up though and I can't figure out what.

If you need more code let me know but I think this covers it all.

Item class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Item implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String m_sItemNumber;

    public String getItemNumber(){return m_sItemNumber;}
    public void setItemNumber(String newVal){m_sItemNumber = newVal;}


    public void setDefaults()
    {
        m_sItemNumber = "notset";
    }

}
```

Inventory class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Inventory implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    MainView mainView;
    LinkedList<Item> Inventory = new LinkedList<>(); 

    int indexOfCurrentItem;

    public void setMainView(MainView view)
    {
        mainView = view;
    }

    public boolean addItem(Item it)
    {
        Inventory.add(it);
        return true;
    }

    public Item getCurrentItem()
    {
        return Inventory.get(indexOfCurrentItem);
    }

    public Item getItemByIndex(int index)
    {
        return Inventory.get(index);
    }

}
```

IOHandler serial save function

```
public boolean saveSerialInv(String arg)
    {
        loadSaveDialog.newStatusLine("   Starting Inventory Save");

        ObjectOutput out = null;
        try 
        {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(arg));
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            loadSaveDialog.newStatusLine("   Could Not Create File");
            return false;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            mainView.newStatusLine("   IO File save Exception");
            return false;
        }

        try 
        {
            out.writeObject(mainView.inventoryOfItems); // !! Fails here. !!
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            loadSaveDialog.newStatusLine("   IO Write-- Exception");
            try 
            {
                    out.close();
        } 
            catch (IOException e1) 
            {
                    loadSaveDialog.newStatusLine("   IO Close save file Exception");
                    return false;
                }
            return false;
        }

        try 
        {
            out.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            loadSaveDialog.newStatusLine("   IO Close save file Exception");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

MainView class

```
public class MainView extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{


    static LoadSaveDialog loadSave = new LoadSaveDialog();
    static ItemInfoDialog itemInfo = new ItemInfoDialog();
    Inventory inventoryOfItems = new Inventory();
    boolean invLoaded = false;

     public MainView() 
     {
        initComponents();
        loadSave.setMainView(this);
        inventoryOfItems.setMainView(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get some exception? If yes post stacktrace.

Comment: In the save function the line `loadSaveDialog.newStatusLine("   IO Write-- Exception");` gets run each time I try to save. So I guess an IOException is thrown?

Comment: Note: [`NotSerializableException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html) is an instance of `IOException`.

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` before that line to see what error you get.

Comment: 'Fails here' is not an adequate problem description. Your question cannot be answered in its present form. Post the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General rule for serialization is that, all the attributes in your class should be `serializable` or marked as `transient`. There is no information about the MainView class whether it is serializable or not, if not then mark it is transient.

```
  MainView mainView;
```

Any non-serializable attribute in your cannot be read/write to/from the object stream. Hence this will fail:

```
        out.writeObject(mainView.inventoryOfItems); // !! Fails here. !!
```

Comment: Ohh. So the references to MainView in my inventory and item class should be marked as `transient`, which means do not try to save it during the serialization?

Comment: @BumSkeeter Anything class reference which is not serializable, you cannot read or read/write to the object stream.

Comment: Well, thank you. It works very nicely now. I guess I set it up differently before. I have never heard of the transient keyword.

Comment: @BumSkeeter Glad to know that it worked :-) In case my answer helped then please accept it. Accepting an answer helps other users facing the same problem.